# Modulus Division With Arrays in C, Malloc (Free)

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free

Print all the numbers divisible by n in the range [start, end]. Program contains 3 variables, Start, End, and n Using C coding. This is what I have so far, I am not sure how to allocate the memory every time a user enters a new start/end value.

```
size_t  = end;
    int *a = malloc((max+1) * sizeof *a);
    if (a) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i <= max; i++){
            a[i] = i;
        free(a);
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: You're supposed to print these numbers. So why are you storing them in memory instead?

Comment: Do you understand how to write a test to tell you whether or not i is divisible by n?  (Hint: what is the "mod" operator?)  Do you understand how to loop from start to end?   Do you understand how to print a number in C?

Comment: `free(a);` move to after for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> size_t  = end;

This line concerns me. I recommend you, doing this:

```
int function(int max){
    int *a = (int*) malloc ( (max+1) * sizeof(int));
    if (a){
        for (int i = 0 ; i<=max ; ++i){
            a[i] = i;
        }
    free(a);
    return (1);
    }
return (0);
}
```

- The function only request the size of the vector, in you case, there is no need for something else, as far as I see.
- I recommend you having a return to int, so you can check if the
  allocation was successfully done or not
- It does not make sense, at least for me, the definition of the size_t. Size_t is a function. Size_t is a function, and, for this reason, it should be called with parenthesis ( ex size_t() ). What goes inside the parenthesis is a type, variable, or something that you want to know the "size of". It is used, in my code as sizeof(int), because you want to know to size of an integer, so you can allocate "integer blocks of memory"
- Dont forget to cast before the malloc. Malloc has return to a void pointer (void*). This means you need to use this cast (int*) if you are going to point to a integer.
- I how are you going to call the function, but, you should considerate changing the max+1 to max. For me it makes more logic.

Comment: Just as a complement, be aware that if the input of the function malloc is 0, you will get some crazy errors/warnings on the copilation

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = start; i<=end; i++){
    if(i%n == 0){
        printf("%d is divisible by %d\n",i,n);
    }
}
```

There's some pseudocode that can get you going. There's no need for dynamic memory if your goal is just to print numbers. You just need a loop through the given range `[start, end]`. Inside you need a condition that checks if a value in the range is divisible by `n`; study up on the mod operator `%`.